# Heterogeneous (JavaEE+JavaScript) application construction

Tags: java, javascript, maven, gruntjs

Imagine a software system that consists of JavaEE backend and JavaScript frontend. Each component employs its own complex build process (Maven for JavaEE backend, Grunt for JavaScript frontend). Each component should remain an independent module, with their own branching and versioning schemes. Moreover, different developer teams will work on backend and frontend. But the final build artifact should be an integrated WAR file with a self-contained (backend+frontend) application.

I'm thinking about implementing the above in the following way:

1. set up individual VCS repositories for backend and frontend;
2. within backend tree, establish a dependency on frontend via SVN externals or git submodule;
3. use [grunt-maven-plugin](https://github.com/allegro/grunt-maven-plugin) to build frontend code from within backend build process.

The only thing that seems fishy to me is maintaining a dependency on a VCS level (SVN externals or git submodule). Any thoughts/suggestions/alternatives? Can this all be done in a better way?

Comment: It sounds like a job for Jenkins, which can manage a dependent build chain of multiple modules. This way your VCS doesn't need to know about the dependency of one project on another.

Comment: Does this imply that both modules are Maven-based? I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this answer which recommends maven-frontend-plugin?

[How to organize full build pipeline with Gulp, Maven and Jenkins, all the way to integration tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865251/how-to-organize-full-build-pipeline-with-gulp-maven-and-jenkins-all-the-way-to/25922758#25922758)

I have had good success building a JavaEE project using the maven-frontend-plugin to run a grunt process as part of the build. We use a dedicated build server and the plugin takes care of the node, npm, grunt installation as part of the build task.