# How to organize build with foundation for apps and Maven?

Tags: angularjs, maven, gulp, zurb-foundation

I have a project that has :

- Java server that is a WAR deployed on Tomcat. It includes all the Java code of my entities, DAO, Service and API.
- JS client built with [Foundation for Apps](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/getting-started.html). It includes Angular JS, Bower, Gulp and Sass.

I'm trying to organize the build process of this project but I have difficulties to implement it.

As said in this post [How to organize full build pipeline with Gulp, Maven and Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865251/how-to-organize-full-build-pipeline-with-gulp-maven-and-jenkins-all-the-way-to), I tried to use the frontend-maven-plugin but without success.

I have the following error :

```
`
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] events.js:141
[ERROR]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[ERROR]       ^
[ERROR] Error: client\assets\scss\_settings.scss
[ERROR] Error: File to import not found or unreadable: helpers/functions
[ERROR]        Parent style sheet: C:/Dev/Code/Porteo/fr.porteo.parent/fr.porteo.jersey/porteo_fa/client/assets/scss/_settings.scss
[ERROR]         on line 32 of client/assets/scss/_settings.scss
[ERROR] >> @import "helpers/functions";
[ERROR]    ^`
```

It would seem there is a problem with the _settings.css file. He don't recognize the tag @import. But where does the problem come from? 
It's surely from maven and the frontent-maven-plugin but how to fix it?

Here my pom.xml with plugin dependencies and executions (only npm start is necessary to run the foundation project) :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- NB! Set <version> to the latest released version of frontend-maven-plugin, like in README.md -->
            <version>0.0.29</version>

            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>my_foundation_project</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>

            <executions>

                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v5.3.0</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>3.3.12</npmVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>npm start</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>start</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>                       
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

So, Have you any solutions or a better way to implement these two applications?

Answer (score 0):

[Issue with similar symptoms](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps/issues/784) - caused by bower permissions mismatch